# PayPal REST API payment states meanings and causes

Tags: rest, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I can't, for the life of me, find the meanings and causes of these PayPal payment states:

`created`; `failed`; `pending`; `canceled`; `expired`, `in_progress`

from the [PayPal REST API documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/).

Downloading and checking the source code of `rest-api-sdk-php` yields nothing as well, but instead added a new state: `partially_completed`

Can anyone point me to the right reference?

I need to be able to handle properly when the payment execution state is anything other than `approved`.

Answer (score 0):

The status field is not specific to RESTful interfaces at Paypal, and the api docs in that respect are not missing anything. I use the following to reference the status fields:

[Paypal Status Reference](https://www.paypal.com/selfhelp/article/FAQ2334?country.x=us&locale.x=en_US)

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. But with respect to the REST API, the source code for getState() has a comment that says the valid return values are only ["created", "approved", "failed", "partially_completed", "in_progress"], of which 3 are not in the link you provided.